# EventEmitter not working with React: event-driven setState() fails

Tags: reactjs

Take a look at the below code, where the user can either click a button to add a random number to the array made by `useState()` or click another button to remove the last number of that array.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { EventEmitter } from 'events'

const emitter = new EventEmitter()

export default () => {
  const [numbers, setNumbers] = useState<number[]>([])

  useEffect(() => {
    emitter.on('add', (data: number) => {
      setNumbers([...numbers, data])
    })
    emitter.on('remove', (data: number) => {
      setNumbers(numbers.filter((item) => item !== data))
    })
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      {numbers.length}
      {numbers.map(n => <div>{n}</div>)}
      <button type='button' onClick={() => emitter.emit('add', Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))}>Add a random number</button>
      <button type='button' onClick={() => emitter.emit('remove', numbers[numbers.length - 1])}>Remove the last number</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I thought this should work but it turned out not to. When there is no number, the adding button works. i.e., it adds a number. But when there is one number, the button doesn't add a number but only changes the number. Below is a brief example of that.

```
(empty) [Initial]
45      [On first click]
67      [On second click]
```

I guess the state has been lost (i.e., the array got empty) by the second click, which re-adds a number in that empty array.

If I get rid of `EventEmitter`, it works. Adding a callback directly to the button, like `onClick={()=>setNumbers([...numbers, 42])}`, solves the problem. But it's not an option. I'm using a custom websocket client that extends `EventEmitter` in reality. I want to register to the client a lot of event-listeners that modify the state (especially, array) so that the DOM changes according to the message from the socket.

I want to know:

1. why that does not work; and
2. how to make it work, without getting rid of `EventEmitter`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState()` does not change the state variable itself captured elsewhere:

> Updating state requests another render with the new state value, but does not affect the count JavaScript variable in your already-running event handler. ([source](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value:%7E:text=Updating%20state%20requests%20another%20render%20with%20the%20new%20state%20value%2C%20but%20does%20not%20affect%20the%20count%20JavaScript%20variable%20in%20your%20already%2Drunning%20event%20handler.))

That's why the code in the question doesn't work as intended. In the following registration,

```
emitter.on('add', (data: number) => {
  setNumbers([...numbers, data])
})
```

`numbers`, empty, gets captured on the creation of the callback. And that empty `numbers` gets reused over and over in that callback.

So, to reference the renewed state, you must store it somewhere, as follows.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    let updatedNumbers: number[] = []
    emitter.on('add', (data: number) => {
      updatedNumbers = [...updatedNumbers, data]
      setNumbers(updatedNumbers)
    })
    emitter.on('remove', (data: number) => {
      updatedNumbers = updatedNumbers.filter((item) => item !== data)
      setNumbers(updatedNumbers)
    })
  }, [])
```

It's not the problem of the event-driven approach nor has anything to do with `EventEmitter`. It's the problem of referencing state.